# Header and footer with content, itextpdf

Tags: itext

My problem is when I try to add the content in the pdf, my table appears from the beginning and not below the header,  my table with content has an incorrect height

The code is something long and I can not upload images, but I have a header and footer with pagination

It looks like it's just adding a space to my table with content but I do not know how to do it, **I think my problem is in the summary method**

```
private void addHeader(PdfWriter writer) {
    PdfPTable tableHeader = new PdfPTable(2);
    try {
        // set default
        tableHeader.setWidths(new int[] { 2, 24 });
        tableHeader.setTotalWidth(527);
        tableHeader.setLockedWidth(true);
        tableHeader.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(40);
        tableHeader.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
        tableHeader.getDefaultCell().setBorderColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        // addImage
        Image img = Image.getInstance(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("imgPDF/logo.png"));
        tableHeader.addCell(img);
        // addText
        PdfPCell text = new PdfPCell();
        text.setPaddingBottom(15);
        text.setPaddingLeft(10);
        text.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
        text.setBorderColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        text.addElement(new Phrase(cve.getId(), new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 13)));
        text.addElement(new Phrase("https://myapp.com", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10)));
        tableHeader.addCell(text);
        // write content
        tableHeader.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 803, writer.getDirectContent());

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
    }

private void summary() throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setHeaderRows(0);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table.setSpacingBefore(15);
    table.setTotalWidth(100);

    // Add headers
    table.addCell(createHeaderCellWithColor("Summary"));
    table.addCell(createHeaderCellWithColor("ACCESS"));
    table.addCell(createCell("row 1"));
    table.addCell(createCell("row 2"));
    table.addCell(createCell("row 3"));

    PdfPTable table3 = new PdfPTable(3);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("aaa"));
    cell.setColspan(3);
    table3.addCell(cell);

    table.addCell(createHeaderCellWithColor("IMPACT"));

    document.add(table);
```

With this I largely resolve,

```
document = new Document (PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 90, 36);
```

Although I would like to download more content, and that is not so close to the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously had this method with a parameter equal to 15, making the content below the header, this more separate ,,, simply equals the fill

***solved with***

```
text.setPaddingBottom(8);
```